# Iterating over a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a less verbose alternative to this:

```
for x in xrange(array.shape[0]):
    for y in xrange(array.shape[1]):
        do_stuff(x, y)
```

I came up with this:

```
for x, y in itertools.product(map(xrange, array.shape)):
    do_stuff(x, y)
```

Which saves one indentation, but is still pretty ugly.

I'm hoping for something that looks like this pseudocode:

```
for x, y in array.indices:
    do_stuff(x, y)
```

Does anything like that exist?

Comment: I am in python 2.7 and am using your solution with the itertools; i read in the comments that using itertools will be faster. however, (maybe cause I am in 2.7) i also had to unpack map in the for loop.
`for x, y in itertools.product(*map(xrange, array.shape)):`

Comment: There's a page in the NumPy Reference called "Iterating Over Arrays": https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493183/most-efficient-way-of-iterating-over-a-numpy-array-by-axis#29495997

Answer (score 217, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [ndenumerate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate).

```
>>> a =numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
>>> for (x,y), value in numpy.ndenumerate(a):
...  print x,y
... 
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
```

Regarding the performance. It is a bit slower than a list comprehension.

```
X = np.zeros((100, 100, 100))

%timeit list([((i,j,k), X[i,j,k]) for i in range(X.shape[0]) for j in range(X.shape[1]) for k in range(X.shape[2])])
1 loop, best of 3: 376 ms per loop

%timeit list(np.ndenumerate(X))
1 loop, best of 3: 570 ms per loop
```

If you are worried about the performance you could optimise a bit further by looking at the implementation of `ndenumerate`, which does 2 things, converting to an array and  looping. If you know you have an array, you can call the `.coords` attribute of the flat iterator.

```
a = X.flat
%timeit list([(a.coords, x) for x in a.flat])
1 loop, best of 3: 305 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note this works but is incredibly slow. You're better of iterating manually.

Answer (score 49):

If you only need the indices, you could try [`numpy.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex):

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in numpy.ndindex(a.shape)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 20):

see [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values)

```
import numpy as np
Y = np.array([3,4,5,6])
for y in np.nditer(Y, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    y += 3

Y == np.array([6, 7, 8, 9])
```

> `y = 3` would not work, use `y *= 0` and `y += 3` instead.

Comment: or use y[...]=3

Answer (score 0):

I see that no good desciption for using [numpy.nditer()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-iterating-over-array/) is here. So, I am gonna go with one.
According to [NumPy v1.21 dev0 manual](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.nditer.html), The iterator object nditer, introduced in NumPy 1.6, provides many flexible ways to visit all the elements of one or more arrays in a systematic fashion.

I have to calculate mean_squared_error and I have already calculate y_predicted and I have y_actual from the boston dataset, available with sklearn.

```
def cal_mse(y_actual, y_predicted):
    """ this function will return mean squared error
       args:
           y_actual (ndarray): np array containing target variable
           y_predicted (ndarray): np array containing predictions from DecisionTreeRegressor
       returns:
           mse (integer)
    """
    sq_error = 0
    for i in np.nditer(np.arange(y_pred.shape[0])):
        sq_error += (y_actual[i] - y_predicted[i])**2
    mse = 1/y_actual.shape[0] * sq_error
    
    return mse
```

Hope this helps :). for further explaination [visit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-iterating-over-array/)