# How to deal with cycling through an unknown number of indexes in an array or list

Tags: python, regex, arrays, recursion

For this example, I had a file containing the names of variables such as foo or bar[4][5] where the names may or may not have a variable number of indexes, as the variables could have been multidimensional arrays. Also inside the dictionary was the starting memory address of each variable, and the type of value it was, such as int_32 or signed_int_64, etc.

My program was supposed to make a print out of each variable, and each component of any arrays, its memory address and its value. The problem was, how do I deal with arrays? They could be one dimensional, two dimensional, twelve dimensional or even zero dimensional (single value) but I needed to get them all with one program. Another important factor was making the program robust enough to endure any number of dimensions.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into trouble? What code have you already written? These are things that you should post when asking a question here on SO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967463/iterating-over-a-numpy-array)

Comment: It's not the same as the numpy array, because this could have up to 20 or possibly more dimensions. And @Josh I posted my solution to the problem below. This was a Q&A post. It was something I figured out on my own, and wanted to share in case someone else had a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solutions was to take the name and check if it matched the regex formula provided by another user of stackoverflow. The following code should be credited to Lib.

```
    def getEntryName(var_string) : # From   LIB @   Stackoverflow.com
      result = re.search(r'(.*?)((?:\[\d*])*)$', var_string)
      var_name = result.group(1)
      numbers   =   re.findall(r'\[(\d+)]', result.group(2))
      return var_name, numbers
```

This returns the base name of a variable and a list called "numbers" which contains all of the indexes of all of the arrays.

Now I used a recurvise call to find iterate through any number of indexes!

```
def BracketHandler( PassedRange, var_name, var_Length, var_startA, numbers )
  for i in range( 0, int( PassedRange ) - 1 ) : # We cycle through it!
    if numbers : # If there are more indexes to cycle through,
      BracketHandler( numbers[0], var_name + "[" + str( i ) + "]",
                    var_Length,  var_startA, numbers[1:] )
    else: # Exit Condition
      ProcessVar(var_name + "[" + str( i ) + "]",
```

var_Length, var_startA)
          var_startA += var_length

Now to explain my code. Basically, before this function is ran, I check to be sure there is anything in numbers, and if there is, I pass this recursive function the first value in numbers, the variable's name, length and starting address and finally the rest of numbers (which mich be = []) once there, I iterate through the current index. Next I check if there are more numbers in the set, and if there are, I tack the current index onto the name, and run through the function again, and do so until there are no new numbers.

At this time, with there being no new numbers, I deal with the variables in another function, and incriment the starting address. And *viola!*

If this code takes a name like foo and a set of numbers like [4, 6, 8] it will produce:

```
foo[0][0][0]
foo[0][0][1]
...
foo[0][0][7]
foo[0][1][0]
...
foo[3][5][7]
```

and send them all to be processed with the correct value!

There might be better solutions, but I wasn't able to find any. I tinkered with this for a long while to make it work as best as I could, and while it may seem obvious to some, it was much less obvious at the time. If you have any suggestions to improve upon it, I welcome it. If there is any error in what I did, feel free to edit my mistakes. If this is not the appropriate way to do a Q&A, let me know, and I will delete this!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of recursion here to get all the coordinates.  For numbers of (say) `[1,3,4]`, you basically want the Cartesian product `[0] x [0,1,2] x [0,1,2,3]`, and that's exactly what `itertools.product` is for:

For example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> numbers = [1, 3, 4]
>>> product(*(range(n) for n in numbers))
<itertools.product object at 0x101abb640>
>>> list(product(*(range(n) for n in numbers)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3)]
```

(Remember that `f(*(a,b,c))` is basically `f(a,b,c)`.)

Wrapping the whole thing up into a generator:

```
def all_coords(name, numbers):
    coords = product(*(range(n) for n in numbers))
    for coord in coords:
        yield name + ''.join('[{}]'.format(c) for c in coord)
```

which would give us

```
>>> list(all_coords("foo", [2,2]))
['foo[0][0]', 'foo[0][1]', 'foo[1][0]', 'foo[1][1]']
>>> for x in all_coords("foo", [2,2]):
...     print x
...     
foo[0][0]
foo[0][1]
foo[1][0]
foo[1][1]
```

Comment: Using this method seems to be optimal. I had no idea itertools existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **`np.ndenumerate`**. For example:

```
for ind,value in np.ndenumerate(myarray):
    print ind, value
```

Will loop over the array giving `ind` as a tuple, which will be `(i,)` for one-dimensional arrays, `(i,j)` for 2D, `(i,j,k)` for 3D and so forth..., and you can access the data always giving retrieving from the array like:

```
`myarray[ind]`
```

allowing you to make a general loop over any array...

Comment: How does this let me access the different indexes? Can I look at var_name[0][3]? And how does this keep track of the appropriate memory address?