# Output row number along with the value in it

Tags: python, search, csv, output

I have this code that looks for a certain value in a huge csv file. Those values are 223.2516 for column 2 in the file which is denoted as "row[2]" and 58.053 for column 3 denoted as "row[3]". I have the code set up so that I can find anything close to those values within an established limit. I know that the value 223.2516 doesnt exist in the file so I'm looking for everything that is relatively close as you can see in the code. The last two commands give an output of all the values:

```
In [54]: [row[2] for row in data if abs(row[2]-223.25)<0.001] 
Out[54]: 
[223.24945646,
 223.25013049,
 223.25093125999999,
 223.24943973000001,
 223.24924296,
 223.24958522]
```

and

```
In [55]: [row[3] for row in data if abs(row[3]-58.053)<0.001]
Out[55]: 
[58.052124569999997,
 58.052942659999999,
 58.053108100000003,
 58.053536250000001,
 58.05346918,
 58.053109259999999,
 58.052188620000003,
 58.052528559999999,
 58.053201559999998,
 58.052009560000002,
 58.052036010000002,
 58.053623790000003,
 58.052450120000003,
 58.052405720000003,
 58.053431590000002,
 58.053709660000003,
 58.053117569999998,
 58.052511709999997]
```

The problem that I have is that I need both values to be within the same row. I'm not looking for the values independent of each other. The 223 value and the 58.0 value both have to be in the same row, theyre coordinates.
Is there a way to output only those values that are in the same row or at least, print the row number in which each value is in, along with the value?
Here's my code:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *

data = np.genfromtxt('result.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1, dtype=float)

[row[2] for row in data if abs(row[2]-223.25)<0.001] 
[row[3] for row in data if abs(row[3]-58.053)<0.001]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967463/iterating-over-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

Question looks familiar.  Use enumerate.  As an example:

```
data = [[3, 222], [8, 223], [1,224], [5, 223]]
A = [ [ind,row[0],row[1]] for ind,row in enumerate(data) if abs(row[1]-223)<1 ]

print A

[[1, 8, 223], [3, 5, 223]]
```

This way, you get the index and you get the pair of values you want.

Take the idea and convert back to your example.  So something like:

```
[ [ind, row] for ind,row in enumerate(data) if abs(row[2]-223.25)<0.001]
```

Answer (score 0):

@brechmos has it. More explicitly, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) allows you to track the implicit index of any iterator as you iterate through it.

```
phrase = 'green eggs and spam':
for ii, word in enumerate(phrase.split()):
  print("Word %d is %s" % (ii, word))
```

Output…

```
Word 0 is green
Word 1 is eggs
Word 2 is and
Word 3 is spam
```