# Loop over all elements of an ndarray one by one

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

```
In [6]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

In [7]: b = a

In [8]: a[0]
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [9]: a[0][0]
Out[9]: 1
```

But I would like to use `zip` and loop through `a` and `b` and get `a[0][0]` followed by `a[0][1]` and so until I reach `a[1][3]`.

When I try the following:

```
In [11]: for i,j in zip(a,b):
    ...:     print i[0][0]
    ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8a9c71fab781> in <module>()
      1 for i,j in zip(a,b):
----> 2     print i[0][0]
      3 

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I'd like to get `a[0][0] = 1` followed by `a[0][1] = 2` up to `a[0][3] = 4`, then get `a[1][0] = 5` and so on up to `a[1][3] = 8`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. What do you want the first few outputs from the loop to be?

Comment: What would you like the output to be? Do you need to loop through _two_ copies of `a`?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I'd like to get `a[0][0] = 1` followed by `a[0][1] = 2` up to `a[0][3] = 4`, then get `a[1][0] = 5` and so on up to `a[1][3] = 8`.

Comment: if you run for loop on a, then your iterate through the element. Use i[0] to print what you want.

Comment: that's what you already have?

Answer (score 6):

If you *just* need to loop through all elements of `a` one by one, that's what [`ndarray.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html) is for:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

In [13]: for i in a.flat: print(i)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Looping over [`a.flatten()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) would produce the same result, but it would construct a separate `ndarray` and copy the data.

`.flat` is also more efficient than `itertools.chain.from_iterable(a)` because the latter involves getting full rows from `a` as views, then iterating over them -- i.e. many extra operations.

---

If you *need to know the indices* while iterating, use [`numpy.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html#numpy.ndenumerate) instead as per [Iterating over a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967463/iterating-over-a-numpy-array):

```
In [34]: for (x,y),i in np.ndenumerate(a): print("a[%d][%d]=%d"%(x,y,i))
a[0][0]=1
a[0][1]=2
a[0][2]=3
a[0][3]=4
a[1][0]=5
a[1][1]=6
a[1][2]=7
a[1][3]=8
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for `chain.from_itable` creating `list` objects? I thought the whole point was it's lazy and *doesn't* create lists.

Comment: @jpp The _source material_ for the `chain` here is complete rows: `for r in a: print(r) => [1 2 3 4]\n[5 6 7 8]`. They are not `list`s but `ndarray`s that point into `a`'s data though, so the overhead it less than I expected but still higher that for `.flat`.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get the zipping and the indices would be to use `np.nditer`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,4)
>>> b = -a
>>> 
>>> it = np.nditer((a, b), order='C', flags=('multi_index',))
>>> for i, j in it:
...     print(it.multi_index, i, j)
... 
(0, 0) 1 -1
(0, 1) 2 -2
(0, 2) 3 -3
(0, 3) 4 -4
(1, 0) 5 -5
(1, 1) 6 -6
(1, 2) 7 -7
(1, 3) 8 -8
```

As a free bonus this does broadcasting where appropriate:

```
>>> a, b = np.ogrid[1:3, 2:6]
>>> a.shape, b.shape
((2, 1), (1, 4))
>>> 
>>> it = np.nditer((a, b), order='C', flags=('multi_index',))
>>> for i, j in it:
...     print(it.multi_index, i, j)
... 
(0, 0) 1 2
(0, 1) 1 3
(0, 2) 1 4
(0, 3) 1 5
(1, 0) 2 2
(1, 1) 2 3
(1, 2) 2 4
(1, 3) 2 5
```

Comment: `np.ndindex` uses the `multi_index` like this to generate the indices of all elements.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [333]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
In [334]: a
Out[334]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

A handy way of getting values along with their indices is `ndenumerate`.

```
In [335]: np.ndenumerate(a)
Out[335]: <numpy.lib.index_tricks.ndenumerate at 0x7f39160b5160>
In [336]: list(_)
Out[336]: 
[((0, 0), 1),
 ((0, 1), 2),
 ((0, 2), 3),
 ((0, 3), 4),
 ((1, 0), 5),
 ((1, 1), 6),
 ((1, 2), 7),
 ((1, 3), 8)]
```

It creates a `iter = a.flat` a `flatiter` object, and then iterates on it returning the `coords` and `next`.

If you just want the values, and not the coordinates as well

```
In [19]: list(a.flat)
Out[19]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`ndindex` can be used to generate indices for a given shape:

```
In [20]: idx=np.ndindex(a.shape)
In [21]: [(ij, a[ij]) for ij in idx]
Out[21]: 
[((0, 0), 1),
 ((0, 1), 2),
 ((0, 2), 3),
 ((0, 3), 4),
 ((1, 0), 5),
 ((1, 1), 6),
 ((1, 2), 7),
 ((1, 3), 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

From your desired output `1, 2, ..., 4, 5, ..., 8`, you can use `itertools.chain` to iterate values:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

for i in chain.from_iterable(a):
    print(i)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 1):

i'll try this

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
for row in [0,1]:
    for column in range(4):
        print('a[%s][%s] = %s' % (row, column, a[row][column]))
```

prints:

```
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[0][2] = 3
a[0][3] = 4
a[1][0] = 5
a[1][1] = 6
a[1][2] = 7
a[1][3] = 8
```